# Add Text Domain To Post Navigation

Tags: posts, navigation

I'm using `previous_post_link('%link','Previous Post');` and     `next_post_link('%link','Next Post');` for post navigation but I want to add text domain to that similar to `_e('Next Post' , 'ft');`

How can I do that?

Comment: Whaaa? Please elaborate, good sir...

Comment: [pre]I'm using : <?php previous_post_link('%link','&larr; Previous Post'); ?> and <?php next_post_link('%link','Next Post &rarr;'); ?>[/pre]

Answer (score 1):

```
previous_post_link( '%link', __( '&larr; Previous Post', 'my_domain' ) );
```

Check out [an explanation of the translator functions](http://wpengineer.com/2237/whats-the-difference-between-__-_e-_x-and-_ex/).

Answer (score 0):

Use it like:

```
<div class="nav-previous"><?php next_posts_link(__( '<span class="meta-nav">&laquo;</span> Older posts', 'your-theme-textdomain' )) ?></div>
<div class="nav-next"><?php previous_posts_link(__( 'Newer posts <span class="meta-nav">&raquo;</span>', 'your-theme-textdomain' )) ?></div>
```

Thanks to Ian Stewart for the bit of codes.